# How do you host multiple sites in the same Azure standard instance?

Tags: azure

I am in the process of setting up a number of sites on our Azure subscription. I currently have one in standard and a few in shared. I would like to move the shared sites to the same standard package but there seems to be no way to do this.

When I navigate to the Scale tab of the web site configuration I see no option of adding other sites to the standard instance. All I see if

> Web Hosting Plan Sites: [name of site]

With no option to add to it. Also, if I try to move a shared site to standard no drop down appears allowing me to select other sites to include.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a website to the same hosting plan, click "NEW" in the command bar at the bottom of the azure management portal, choose to create a website and, in the "Web Hosting Plan" textbox, select your existing plan instead of creating a new one.
Once you do this, you can go in Scale tab and see your second website in the list.

To do the same thing in a Cloud Service instead of a website, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg433110.aspx

Comment: Pretty sure that's not true?
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PennyPinchingInTheCloudWhenDoAzureWebsitesMakeSense.aspx

Standard websites support up to 500 sites.

Comment: Hi Sergio, I WAS pretty sure but I was WRONG. Sorry. I edited my answer with the information I got by making some tests.

Comment: Ype, seems to be the to go. This is a little more clear to see in the new azure management portal although to switch a site from one plan to another you still have to use powershell.

Comment: @Sergio Do you have sample Powershell scripts or some reference data for me? Thanks.