# How to move Azure WebSite into current Standard mode VM

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have few Azure WebSites using Standard mode with only 1 instance.  All the WebSites located within the same VM at the same time.  I added a new WebSite recently.  I don't know how to put this new website into the current Standard mode website.  Few weeks ago, I can just click website and join to the same Standard mode VM.  But the UI has changed.  I couldn't find it anymore.  Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

If your looking for an option to change "Web Hosting Plan Mode" from Share/Free to standard you can find it in the **Scale** section of **Websites** extension in the Management Portal.

I'm still not sure if your using any tool/IDE like Visual Studio to publish your website, if yes let me know !! Happy Coding

Comment: As I know, the Azure WebSite Standard mode could contains 500 websites within the Standard mode VM.  I don't know how to put all these websites into the same VM.  Do you know what I mean?

Comment: Probably this is what you are looking for : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21011047/multiple-web-sites-on-single-windows-azure-web-sites-instance

Comment: This URL also talks about the same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22837155/how-do-you-host-multiple-sites-in-the-same-azure-standard-instance

Comment: It can't pick up website in the Scale tab anymore.  It's been replaced for "Web Hosting Plan".  I can create a NEW site using the current "Web Hosting Plan".  But I can't MOVE my current website into current "Web Hosting Plan".